# Meteor Session variable not showing Reactive property: not re-rendering after removing key from Session

Tags: javascript, session, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-blaze

When I set a key in Session the code is re-rendered, but when I remove that key from Session it doesn't re-render.

In my `images` template I'm listening click event and setting an ID to the Session. When Session is changed it re-renders the `images` template. But When I listen to another click event and set that Session key to undefined (even tried to delete that key) no re-rendering happens.

My code snippet is attached.

**Explanation of code snippet:** There are one `template helpers` and one `template events` in the .js file. When meteor app is run `getFilteredUser` function checks whether there is any filter key available in session, then it renders the `images` template. The helper function `images` binds the data based on the status Session variable.

When `js_set_image_filter` is called it updates the Session variable and the `images` template is re-rendered. When `js_remove_image_filter` is called it again updates the Session variable, but the `image` template is not re-rendered this time.

Why doesn't the template re-render at the second time?

blaze template:

```
<body>
    <div class="container">
        {{#if getFilteredUser}}
            <p>Showing images for  "{{getFilteredUser}}" </p>
            <p> <a href="#" class="js_remove_image_filter">  Click Here </a> to remove all filters!</p>
        {{else}}
            <p> Showing all images, no filted is applied! </p>
        {{/if}}
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        {{> images}}
    </div>
</body>

<template name="images">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each images}}
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail" id="{{_id}}">
                    <img  class="thumbnail_image" src= "{{a}}" />
                        <div class="js-image">
                            <p>Created by: <a href="#"  class="js_set_image_filter">  {{getuser userid}} </a> </p>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</template>
```

js file:

```
import {Images} from "/import/images.js";

Template.body.helpers({
  getFilteredUser: function(){
    var user = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: Session.get("userFilter")});
    if(user) return user.username;
    else return undefined;
  },
});

Template.body.events({
  "click .js_remove_image_filter": function(event) {
    delete  Session.keys["userFilter"];
    Session.keys = {};
    Session.set("userFilter", undefined );
  }
});

Template.images.helpers({
  images: function(){
    if(Session.get("userFilter"))
      return Images.find({userid: Session.get("userFilter")}, {sort:{date: -1, rating: -1}});
    else  return Images.find({}, {sort:{date: -1, rating: -1}});
  },
  getuser: function(userid){
    if(Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userid}))
      return Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userid}).username;
    else return "annonymus";
  }
});

Template.images.events({
  "click .js_set_image_filter" : function(event){
    Session.set("userFilter", this.userid);
  }
});
```

First screenshot is initial view of the app, when I click on the Created By field, it put the creators into the Session variable and renders the filtered items only. But when I click on remove filter, the `js_remove_image_filter` function is called and it modifies the Session too. But no re-rendering happens.

[image: First screenshot]
[image: After Filter]

Comment: Can you try putting whatever is in the ```<body>``` in another template and then call the template within the body just like you did with the ```images``` template? Lets see if you're able to get the session unset to respond from there.

Comment: @blueren followed it, didn't work yet

Comment: I'm not finding a reason as to why it shouldn't work yet. Are you sure that the code is reachable within the event? If you ```console.log``` the ```Session``` variable after it's been unset, does it return the undefined as expected?

Comment: yes, I've printed log just before and after the setting the Session and it works properly.

Comment: Would you be able to rerender the template via ```Template.autorun``` ? As an example - Template.something.onRendered(function() {
  ```var self = this;
  self.autorun(function() {
        // some reactive operation
   });```

Comment: I'm not sure whether the I need to run `images` function in `Template.images.helper` to generate the data again. But it won't be reactive anymore in that case, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124744/discussion-between-mostafiz-and-blueren).

Comment: I think you shouldn't unset the session variable, as if you do, it can't watch it any more. It's probably better to set it to and empty string, '', or something that won't return any data.

Comment: @mostafiz - I'd earlier replied over the chat section, not sure if you got a chance to read through that. I took a look at my implementation of Sessions in my local project and it's actually in line with what @MikeKing says om the above comment. Nowhere have I actually ```unset``` the Session. Basically if you unset it, the variable is gone. Try using true falst values to the Session variable and see if that works out.

Comment: I'd already solved the issue. You people are right! `delete  Session.keys["userFilter"]` or `Session.keys = {}` removes the key totally, but it worked when I set the key `undefined`